# tensorflow (tf) variable initialize shape bug?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

The below code aims to build "sy_logprob_n" by a while loop and fill in one row dim each loop. But when I run this, it says

> ValueError: Index out of range using input dim 0; input has only 0
>   dims for 'while/strided_slice_1' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input
>   shapes: [], [1], [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[3] =
>   <1>.

And one thing wierd is that when I print out the shape as `print(tf.shape(sy_logprob_n),tf.shape(sy_ac_na))`, their two shapes are different:

> Tensor("Shape_2:0", shape=(0,), dtype=int32) Tensor("Shape_3:0",
>   shape=(2,), dtype=int32)

But "sy_logprob_n" was initialized by the shape of "sy_ac_na".

Anyone has idea? Thanks in advance!!!

```
sy_ac_na = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, ac_dim], name="ac", dtype=tf.float32) 
batch_size=tf.shape(sy_ob_no)[0]

  sy_mean = build_mlp(sy_ob_no, ac_dim, 'mean', n_layers, size) # shape (batch,ac_dim)
  sy_logstd = tf.Variable(initial_value=0,name='std',expected_shape=[ac_dim],dtype=tf.float32) # logstd should just be a trainable variable, not a network output.
  sy_sampled_ac=tf.random_normal(tf.shape(sy_ac_na),mean=sy_mean,stddev=tf.exp(sy_logstd),seed=seed) # shape(batch,ac_dim)
  sy_logprob_n=tf.Variable(initial_value=0,expected_shape=tf.shape(sy_ac_na),name='sy_logprob_n',dtype=tf.float32)
  print(tf.shape(sy_logprob_n),tf.shape(sy_ac_na))

  def cond(sy_logprob_n,i,sy_ac_na):
    return tf.less(i,batch_size)

  def body(sy_logprob_n,i,sy_ac_na):
    distribution=tf.distributions.Normal(sy_mean,tf.exp(sy_logstd))
    log_prob=distribution.log_prob(sy_ac_na[i,:])
    tf.assign(sy_logprob_n[i],log_prob)
    i+=1
    return sy_logprob_n

  sy_logprob_n = tf.squeeze(tf.while_loop(cond,body,[sy_logprob_n,0,sy_ac_na]))  # shape (batch,)
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though you specified the `expected_shape`, the `tf.Variable` will take the shape of `initial_value` (0 for your case here) as its shape. It seems that the `expected_shape` argument has been [deprecated](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8753e2ebde6c58b56675cc19ab7ff83072824a62/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py#L284) since v1.0.0. I'm not sure why it is still documented with `tf.Variable`. I just filed an issue on Github.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is really confusing. By the way, do you know how I can implement this if the tf.Variable does not work?

Comment: @Billadsf I'm not quite sure what your purpose is but it is generally recommended [using `tf.get_varible` to create a variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables). Hopefully this is the answer you're looking for...